# colorize hostname in command line prompt

Tags: bash, colors, prompt, konsole

I wish to set a custom color for the hostname portion of my command line prompt (in bash).

In my `.bashrc` file, the default command line prompt is:

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

To colorize the hostname only, I came up with this prompt:

```
PS1='[\u@\e[40;36m\h\e[0m \W]\$ '
```

I used different colors for each host I work on. The colorizing part seems to be working as expected. However, with the prompt above, navigation on the command line becomes dysfunctional. For example, at times I cannot move the cursor to the beginning or end of the line. If I switch back to the default prompt, everything works correctly again.

What's wrong with my colorized prompt? How can I properly specify a color for the hostname only?

It should not matter for this question, but I'm running Arch Linux KDE and I work in Konsole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Background

After the expansion is done for special prompt sequences, every character remaining in the prompt is counted in order to calculate the length of the prompt.

#### Problem

Since you've added the color sequences, which in fact shouldn't be counted for the length of a prompt, `bash` now actually thinks that your prompt is longer than it really is.
Because of that, `bash` can't know where is the beginning or the end of the line and that creates mentioned dysfunctionalities.

#### Solution

From `bash` manual:

> ```
> \[    Begin a sequence of non-printing characters, which could be used to 
>       embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt
>
> \]    End a sequence of non-printing characters
> ```

Just add these around your color escape sequences so that they aren't counted for the prompt length.